# How should I display a png file using pdftex

Tags: graphics, pdftex, plain-tex

I has been over 10 years since I needed to display graphics using TeX. Previously I would use:

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
```

and later something like

```
\includegraphics{Fig_02.png} \hfil
```

Now, TeXworks tells me that I have an undefined control sequence in my `\usepackage` statement. My searches on the web to find out how this is done currently keeps referring me to LaTeX.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Additionally, the `[pdftex]` option is rarely (if ever) needed any more. The `graphicx` package and others can almost always detect whether they're being run under `pdftex` or other engines.

Comment: But there is no problem in the `\usepackage` statement itself, even though it is better not to specify the `pdftex` option if you don't need to.

Comment: Mike, thank you for your answers. I am using Tex, not LaTex. I believe your document comments apply to LaTex. That being the case, my question remains. How should I display a png file using pdftex? Or using Tex?

Comment: \usepackage{graphicx}
\includegraphics{Figure10.png}
\bye

Comment: A file, G.tex, with the three lines above would have produced a pdf file containing Figure10.png 15 years ago. How do I display the png in a tex file now?  Obviously, in practice there will be more tex statements.

Comment: @MackElrod Two things: 1) If you have `\usepackage` then it sounds very much like you are using LaTeX not plain (where `\input graphics` would be usual) and 2) We are going to need to see a log for a MWE.

Answer (score 5):

Before answering, let me ask again: Do you really want to use *plain* TeX?

If so, here's a document that should compile with `pdftex`:

```
\input miniltx
\input graphicx

\includegraphics{Figure10.png} 

\bye
```

Comment: Problem solved! The answer to your question is a bit more complicated.  But since you favored me with an answer I should do the same. I started using plain Tex in the late 1980's and over some years developed a set of macro's that allow me to do just about anything I wish. Now I use Tex very infrequently and question whether it is worth it to me to come up the LaTex learning curve.  Thank you so much for your assistance.